# Once-off schedule flow not running for all account records

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-flow-builder, flow-builder

I am migrating customer preferences on the `Account` Object to a related Object `Customer Preferences` using a flow.

This only needs to be done once.

- I have added a checkbox field to the `Account` Object which is updated when the preferences have been migrated to the new Object for that `Account` record.
- If the checkbox is unchecked, the flow will create a new preference record for the `Account`.

I ran the flow using a Schedule trigger and it successfully ran with no errors. I created a report to check if all the `Account` Objects' checkboxes are checked and found that of the almost 10000 records, about 250 records were not processed.

I manually debugged the flow using the `recordid` of one of the unprocessed records and it created the new preference record without any errors.

I re-ran the scheduled flow, but the 250 (-1 for the record I created through the flow debugger) records remained unprocessed.

My flow is working correctly, which lets me believe that there is an issue of how the `Account` records are processed. I don't have an in-depth knowledge of schedule triggered flows, but could there be an issue with batching, or should I maybe try another flow trigger?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you get any record locking errors (sent to the `Setup | Process Automation` configured email address (or possibly some other exception)?

Comment: @cropredy that was the first place I went to see if there were any errors that came through. There were no email error messages. No other errors popped up either.

Comment: If the 250 recs fail to be processed despite rerunning the flow then a) flow logic error, b) some exception/rollback occurring ,c) Limits exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most plausible issue I could think about is these records having fields that are mandatory, but not populated.  When the process runs, it is skipping records it can't update and save again because of missing data in the mandatory field.

Comment: It ended up being a unique field that was getting duplicates written to it! Thanks for the help!